# make div always in bottom

Tags: css

I have problem with div this code

```
<div class="parent" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="first" style="position: absolute;">
        images etc ..
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <ul>
            ... etc
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

parent div with no height because I'm working in responsive design 
the problem is the second div is always in top and need margin-top : Xpx;
to be in the bottom of parent , but this make problem in responsive because if height of first is smaller than margin-top : Xpx; Will show free space

thank's

Comment: why use `position:absolute` for the first div?

Comment: this images slider , I try using relative in first div and the result is same

Comment: When you say _bottom_, do you mean the second div should be after the first one, or it should be stick to the bottom of the parent?

Comment: I can't understand you but I need it like no postion <div>1</div></div>2</div>

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used this code as like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="first">
images etc ..
</div>
<div class="second">
<ul>
... etc
</ul>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.first{
position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:red;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

live demo http://tinkerbin.com/UrrM7EIv

Comment: the problem when add parent div with position relative this example : http://tinkerbin.com/ZsLf6bJE

Comment: Hey @user533178 i think you want to this http://tinkerbin.com/ZPsLxUP3   and now absolute position is required height if you don't give to height than same height give to parent relative to padding equal to absolute position height .......